# How to get the Kafka consumer offset info in the Flink program

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using Flink's FlinkKafkaConsumer010 and Kafka version 1.1. 
I want to get the offset lag info in my code

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a external tool like Burrow, which can track lag for *all Kafka consumers* rather than just your Flink apps

Answer (score 1):

[Flink Kafka Connector Metric](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/metrics.html#Connectors)

committedOffsets: The last successfully committed offsets to Kafka, for each partition. A particular partition's metric can be specified by topic name and partition id.

currentOffsets: The consumer's current read offset, for each partition. A particular partition's metric can be specified by topic name and partition id.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I don't understand too much. Is there a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

```
val endOffset = new PartitionOffsetsRetrieverImpl(
      kafkaConsumer,
      kafkaAdminClient,
      "group_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
    ).endOffsets(util.Arrays.asList(topicPartition)).get(topicPartition)
```

Here kafkaConsumer is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer obj

and kafkaAdminClient is org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient obj

This could be improved,  because with this every time it creates the instance of kafka consumer and that is not efficient.